# how to play .3GP video file in android

Tags: android, android-videoview

HI 
i want to play a .3GP video file in android phone. i tried below code but it shows cant play video.so please tell me what i will do

This is my code

```
 public class VideoPlay extends Activity {

private String path ;
private VideoView mVideoView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.videoplay);
    path="http://www.boodang.com/api/videobb/101009_Pure.3gp";
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);

    if (path == "") {
        // Tell the user to provide a media file URL/path.
        Toast.makeText(
                VideoPlay.this,
                "Please edit VideoViewDemo Activity, and set path"
                        + " variable to your media file URL/path",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {

        /*
         * Alternatively,for streaming media you can use
         * mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(URLstring));
         */
        mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        mVideoView.requestFocus();

    }
}
}
```

The XML layout is

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <FrameLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <VideoView
  android:id="@+id/video"
   android:layout_width="320px"
   android:layout_height="240px">
   </VideoView>
   </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following code which is there in the Android SDK demo

```
package com.example.android.apis.media;

import com.example.android.apis.R;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.MediaController;

import android.widget.Toast;

import android.widget.VideoView;

public class VideoViewDemo extends Activity {

    /**
     * TODO: Set the path variable to a streaming video URL or a local media
     * file path.
     */
    private String path = "";
    private VideoView mVideoView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.videoview);
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);

        if (path == "") {
            // Tell the user to provide a media file URL/path.
            Toast.makeText(
                    VideoViewDemo.this,
                    "Please edit VideoViewDemo Activity, and set path"
                            + " variable to your media file URL/path",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {

            /*
             * Alternatively,for streaming media you can use
             * mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(URLstring));
             */
            mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
            mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
            mVideoView.requestFocus();

        }
    }
}
```

videoview.xml

```
<VideoView 
    android:id="@+id/surface_view" 
    android:layout_width="320px"
    android:layout_height="240px"
/>
```

Comment: what exactly is the error ?   also try with a different .3gp file

Comment: 01-27 21:04:32.952: ERROR/PlayerDriver(31): Command PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or info UNKNOWN PVMFStatus
01-27 21:04:32.952: ERROR/MediaPlayer(1559): error (200, -32)
01-27 21:04:32.952: ERROR/MediaPlayer(1559): Error (200,-32)

Comment: Android plays both 3gp & mp4 files, unless there is some frame rate / bit rate issue. Send me your code if you want , I'll check whether the code is an issue or your video file

Comment: i pasted my code in above plz check the above code and tell me solution

Comment: seems an issue with the url ... try with this sample url "http://daily3gp.com/vids/747.3gp" . It should work

Comment: Make sure you have added in your Android Manifest file the permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: can be issues with your connectivity ... do one thing .. just copy & paste both the urls in your internet browser & check whether there are being played or not .....if possible send me your project in my mail id .. I'll get back to you .. mail Id : remember_chiranjib@yahoo.co.in

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-videoview-example/) provides code similar to your sample, though there are some differences, especially with `video.start` and your sample completely missing `MediaController.show`.

I suggest cleaning up your code a bit and try the suggestions found in the mentioned article. There's also some good feedback in the article discussions.

Comment: Thanks for giving reply . i tried your link it shows cant play this video it is only for mp4link? i want to play .3GP file

Comment: People in the discussion suggest code that shows .3gp files as well.

Answer (score 0):

As @Peter Lillevold suggests, you should try a reference implementation of a video player first.  Here are some links:

- [Audio and Video](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html)
- [MediaPlayer Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)
- [Android VideoView Example](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-videoview-example/)

Try these players with a known working video file, there is a link to some in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544365/android-cant-play-any-videos-mp4-mov-3gp-etc/2545006#2545006).  If you implement a player, and these reference videos work, but your .3gp video does not, then the problem may be that the video file itself is not encoded to standards.