# How to Play local swf files in a webview

Tags: android, webview

Am trying to play local .swf files (kept in asset or sdcard) inside webview. But am not getting any luck...Can anyone guide me the proper way???
I am able to play swf files via url....but getting difficulty in playing local file inside webview

Comment: What URL do you use to play it via the Browser? That should be the URL you should point your `WebView` to.

Comment: Am using the code as: <html >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Flash</title>
</head>

<body>
<object width="550" height="400">
<param name="movie" value="circa-med.swf"">
<embed src="http://circa-med.org/circa-med.swf" width="550" height="400">
</embed>
</object>

</body>
</html> Its working fine...Instead the url I want to use the code as <embed src=\"file:///sdcard/sample.swf\" to take the file from sdcard

Comment: how you have played swf or flv video will provide some reference for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

swf2.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <object width="215" height="140">
      <param name="movie" value="choudanse7us.swf">
        <embed src="file:///mnt/sdcard/choudanse7us.swf"
               width="215" height="140">
        </embed>
    </object>
  </body>
</html>
```

below is the android code

```
package webView.video;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
private WebView mWebView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
     public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super. onCreate (savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);



         // html file with sample swf video in sdcard

         //swf2.html points to swf in sdcard

         mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
         mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
         mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);


         if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
             System.exit(4);
         } else {
             mWebView.loadUrl("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/swf2.html");
         }

     }
}
```

Comment: i have tried the same code but got this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308712/how-to-run-the-swf-file-in-android-emulator   how to solve this?

Comment: @VENKI did you get answer to your question? I faced the same problem, and in my application also it was showing that blue colored cube with question mark symbol. I managed to solve it. I had flash installed in my device and still I was getting that cube. Let me know if you need the answer.

Comment: in ur manifest file. add following `android:hardwareAccelerated="true">` inside `<application></application>`  e.g.: `<application
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            ///// activity code.
        </activity>
    </application>`

Answer (score 6):

For assets:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/YourFile.swf");
```

will play the file auto-scaled to the WebView size.

---

For the SD card, I expect something like this would work:

```
if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
    Log.d(TAG, "No SDCard");
} else {
    webView.loadUrl("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/YourPath/YourFile.swf");
}
```

(Using the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, of course).

Edit: You may also need to set:

```
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
```

Comment: Thanks but my doubt is while running swf file in browser (from server) we use these lines: "<param name=\"movie\" value=\"circa-med.swf\"> " +
    "<embed src=\"http://circa-med.org/circa-med.swf\" width=\"160\" height=\"180\"> " +
    "</embed>"+
    "</object>" ........But for local file how to give path  under<embed> tag

Comment: Well, the first question is whether you need it to be embedded in a web page at a specific pixel size... if not, the above solution may be more useful.   If you do need it embedded, does `<param name=\"movie\" value=\"file:///android_asset/YourFile.swf\">...` work for assets? If it does, you could probably edit the HTML string programmatically to include the results of `"file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/YourPath/YourFile.swf"` as the embedded file, for files on the SD card.

Comment: You'd still need to set `setAllowFileAccess(true)` and add the Permission as mentioned above, of course, for reading from the SD card.

Comment: I have tried the code as : _webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/sample.3gp"); I kept sample.3gp inside asset folder but no output in screen ..Please help me out

Comment: I have tried the code as : _webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/sample.3gp"); I kept sample.3gp inside asset folder but no output in screen ..Please help me out – – @Sven Viking

Comment: Afraid I haven't worked with .3gp files before -- I didn't know the Android WebView even supported them. **EDIT**: I just did some quick Googling, and from what I can see I'm pretty sure the WebView cannot load .3gp files.

Comment: Looks as if a VideoView would be needed for 3gp video. Related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818047/how-to-play-3gp-video-file-in-android

Comment: Ok...so Iam trying with swf alternative for 3gp .. Here is my code.....        _linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        _webview = new WebView(this);
  _linearLayout.addView(_webview);
  setContentView(_linearLayout); 
        _webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  _webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
  _webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);    
  String url = "file:///android_asset/sample.swf";
  _webview.loadUrl(url);                        Iam gettin a blank screen ..Please help me....@Sven Viking

Comment: The problem is just that the WebView has no height or width. Change the addView line to: `linearLayout.addView(webview, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);` . I just tried this myself, and it worked fine.

Comment: I'm actually pretty new to Android development myself, but if you do need to contact me, you can find details on the website linked from my user page.

Answer (score 0):

```
package webView.video;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
private WebView mWebView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
     public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super. onCreate (savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);



         // html file with sample swf video in sdcard

         //swf2.html points to swf in sdcard

         mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
         mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
         mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);


         if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
             System.exit(4);
         } else {
             mWebView.loadUrl("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/swf2.html");
         }

     }
}
```