# android application - interactive swf file not properly working through WebView control

Tags: java, android, virtual, android-sdcard, swfloader

I want to clarify one doubt ..How we can properly load an interactive swf file in an android application.?

In case with a non-interactive swf file its OK..i can able to display it properly.
But in case with an interactive swf file its display OK, but it is not getting working properly. Its drop down box not working. We cant't get select any item from the drop-down box.

I have included code for enabling javascript and all.

```
     webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
     webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Can anyone please tell the proper way in which we can load an interactive swf file into an android application.?

Comment: Have you checked this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106636/how-to-play-local-swf-files-in-a-webview

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [Load an SWF into a WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994116/load-an-swf-into-a-webview)

You have to enable plugins.

```
webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

Comment: i already enabled plugins using this line of code.but its not working.

Comment: What error are you getting? What is happening or what is not happening? Please update your question to describe more fully the problem you are facing. Thanks!