# How to run .swf Files on Android Device

Tags: android, flash

I am new to android and just started working on flash objects, by which i mean .swf files. I have read a lot about using a web view to load the swf file stored in assets/SD location, but to no avail. i have got suggestions from [How to Play local swf files in a webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106636/how-to-play-local-swf-files-in-a-webview) , flash players, Adobe AIR features of setting an swf to make an apk, etc. But still i am not being able to run the .swf files satisfactorily, due to the following reasons :

1. Even thought i set everything as set in the above link, i am getting a blank screen, much to my dismay of flash player not currently being default ("Launch by Default" Option in Setting->Apps->Flash Player->Launch By Default), hence i can't run flash content.
2. I have applied Adobe AIR to actually get the apk of the swf file by following a lengthy process, but because of two reason : a) Very laborious process and b) per-Installation requirement of Adobe AIR makes the whole purpose a losing battle.
3. Lots of Jargon/Confusion in Flash and lots of news on how flash is not making updates to its products for mobile sector, and how android "has"/"trying to" move into html 5.

I would like you all to solve this remedy to get flash swf object running on Android with minimum plugin ad-dons to the browser. I would love to have the has less support files as possible for my work to be productive and educative as well.

I hereby attach a code snippet, which i was working to get the work done to get the swf file running :

1. Approach One :

   ```
       import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
       import android.app.Activity;
       import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.webkit.WebSettings;
       import android.webkit.WebView;
       import android.widget.LinearLayout;

       @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
       public class SWFViewer extends Activity {
       WebView wvswf;
       LinearLayout linearLayout;
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_swfviewer);
           linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
           wvswf = new WebView(SWFViewer.this);
           wvswf.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
           wvswf.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
           wvswf.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
           linearLayout.addView(wvswf, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

       String Url = "file:///android_asset/main.swf";
       wvswf.loadUrl(Url);

           }

   }
   ```

With the layout as :

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.winit.nunna.swfviewer"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:maxSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.winit.nunna.swfviewer.SWFViewer"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

2. Approach Two

Using Adobe AIR SDK, we create an apk using the main swf file, some xml files for configuration and app signing, we can release an apk.

Conclusion : The first is the easiest but no o/p

```
12-20 13:56:28.457: INFO/WindowManager(162): MediaPlayer.is not PlayingVideo
```

The later is cumbersome with lots of extra dependencies.

Please give me better options to get an affordable aka high/moderate performance Flash O/p.

Comment: Note that Flash is no longer supported for Android, by decision of Adobe.

Comment: i am not able to understand the meaning of "Flash not supported in Android", it would be a huge help if you could explain me about that, also I am now reading about SWFObject, which i think can be used in HTML5 for flash objects in a non-flash way, please comment on that too.
Thanks

Comment: If you use a search engine to search for `android flash` you find http://www.theverge.com/2012/8/14/3241727/flash-for-android-dies and http://www.zdnet.com/androids-flash-player-is-dead-live-with-it-7000002668/ and http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/adobe-flash-for-android-gone-with-barely-a-whimper/ and http://readwrite.com/2012/08/14/adobe-flash-on-android-rip and http://www.webmonkey.com/2012/08/no-more-flash-for-android/ and http://tech.slashdot.org/story/12/08/15/1441200/adobe-officially-kills-new-flash-installations-on-android and others. AIR may still be available.

Comment: Thanks for the info on Flash Death, but i would like to know how i can use the still littering flash objects made till now, which if i don't implement, then i need to create a hell of a lot of code to show the effect from scratch. I would like to know any methods, by which we can get the content from flash and use it to show to the same effect. Also comment more on SWFObject.

Comment: Is there any way to use the existing flash content (i mean archaic flash content) in android using some library extension, plugins or configuration? If so please let me know.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have read about AIR, but i am getting a very confused set of information regarding AIR, can you please guide me towards a good AIR tutorial or so, it would be highly appreciable.

Comment: For all those who are trying to integrate flash content, there is way through Adobe Air, there is a lot of command line and other technical jargon to be followed. Search for Adobe Air for Android, and your problem is solved !

Comment: @Shri Krishna Hi , I want to develop such a application that play swf file in android device without any third party dependency. I have search a lot on google but not found any feasible solution. Please give me hint that how can i start? is Adobe AIR is good choice ? Please give me important link if you have. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to integrate swf files in native android (Java) code w/o using WebView.

If you state that your problem is solved by building an APK with Adobe AIR using the same swf then i think you did remedy your problem of getting the swf to android, but not actually do what you asked for in the question above.