# Showing Flash content in android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

There is need where i want to show the flash content in my android app. I want to know that what's the better way to do that. And if I have the flash resource so where should I keep that in my project i.e whether inside res folder or anywhere else.

One more thing is that if flash is interactive like if its having some buttons and clicking on it will lead me to some other things so how to achieve it.
Any link of some good tutorial's will also be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In **WebView** we can display flash content (.swf). But I don't know weather it is possible or not with controls in flash content we can achieve output.

Check this link, it may help you.

[How to Play local swf files in a webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106636/how-to-play-local-swf-files-in-a-webview)

Comment: Yugandhar:can u help me with some tutorials link.?

Comment: as per your suggestion I am able to achieve the requirement but still i want to know that is their any way to show the flash content on activity that is by not opening the webView.