# Flash File Play On Application Startup

Tags: android, flash

Is it possible to play flash file as the startup for my application? i would be just like the flash file plays itself on the startup of the application and jump into the application! How can i do this? Example would be appreciated

Comment: Here's a comprehensive answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6407565/1025599

Comment: whats the html about in your reference link??

Comment: That example loads a webview that has an html file containing the swf object. Based on the answer below i suppose you can load the swf directly without needing an html page.

Comment: Thank You! after the lines of code below i would be able to start my application activity through intent??

Answer (score 1):

Make SplashActivity and try this:

```
WebView webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_play);

File decfile = new File("/mnt/sdcard/flashplay/temp/test.swf");

Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(decfile);

if(decfile.exists()){

    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webview.loadUrl(uri.toString());
}
```