# Can It play flash files on Android?

Tags: android, flash

The Android supports flash files?

How I can integrate this?

- WebView??
- Integrate with some tool of Adobe??

The idea is have local flash files and play that inside of my application.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer:**
Yes, you can play flash files in android app using just a Webview.

**Long Answer:**
You have to create an html file with embedded swf file. See sample here http://pastebin.com/BYrfKmea
After that You can put html and swf files in assets folder and try opening it in a WebView by 
  `mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/player.html");`.

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106636/how-to-play-local-swf-files-in-a-webview) also might be useful.

Comment: Is this continue work with latest versions of Android (KitKat, Lolipop and Marshmallow)?

Comment: @user847695 Flash Player **is no longer officially supported by Android**, but you can install it at your own risk.

Comment: @akmozo, I have this idea, but I have a requirement to play flash files :(
For this reason i asked how can do it.

Comment: @user847695 If you want just to install Flash Player in your Android device, you can take a look [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/installing-flash-player-android-devices.html) ...