# Android not playing the video file from a given url

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to play a video file in Android activity but not able to do this

I am using the  following code.

```
try
  {

    VideoView video = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);

     String url="http://demofouracelimited.com/modigynw/
    videos/VID_20140730_144814_1407834444.3gp"

   String url1="http://download.itcuties.com/teaser/itcuties-teaser-480.mp4"

    video.setVideoPath(url); //  not playing
    // video.setVideoPath(url1); playing

      video.start();
 }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    ex.printStackTrace();    
   }
```

can you help me to fix problem in this task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `public void setVideoURI (Uri uri)`. Have you tried using `Uri.parse(url)` to see if the video plays?

Is there anything in the logcat?

Also, is it necessary to use a `VideoView`? Will using the `MediaPlayer` suit your need? :)

Comment: hmm piyush the video is being played with the second url but not with first one url and not throwing any error

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818047/how-to-play-3gp-video-file-in-android

Comment: @adeshsingh if you refer to the [supported formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) for MediaPlayer, `3gp` is supported straight out of the box :)