# Unable to create MediaPlayer, error for a soundboard

Tags: android, media-player

when debugging i get unable to create MediaPlayer

The app loads and then hangs when i click on a button for sound.
Here is the logcat errors
i can't seem to find what went wrong.

```
04-03 16:00:17.273: ERROR/gralloc(61): [unregister] handle 0x4456d0 still locked (state=40000001)
04-03 16:00:22.793: ERROR/PlayerDriver(31): Command PLAYER_PREPARE completed with an error or info PVMFErrResource
04-03 16:00:22.803: ERROR/MediaPlayer(279): error (1, -17)
04-03 16:00:17.273: ERROR/gralloc(61): [unregister] handle 0x4456d0 still locked (state=40000001)
```

Here is my code.

```
package com.yes.hotrod;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class main extends Activity {
MediaPlayer FilmSound=new MediaPlayer();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
            R.raw.animalkingdom);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (FilmSound.isPlaying()) {
                FilmSound.stop();
                FilmSound.reset();
                FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.raw.animalkingdom);
                FilmSound.start();
            } else {
                FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.raw.animalkingdom);
                FilmSound.start();
            }
        }
    });

    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
            R.raw.bigassstunt);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (FilmSound.isPlaying()) {
                FilmSound.stop();
                FilmSound.reset();
                FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.raw.bigassstunt);
                FilmSound.start();
            } else {
                FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.raw.bigassstunt);
                FilmSound.start();
            }
        }
    });
    Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer
            .create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.godsofwar);
    button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (FilmSound.isPlaying()) {
                FilmSound.stop();
                FilmSound.reset();
                FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.raw.godsofwar);
                FilmSound.start();
            } else {
                FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.raw.godsofwar);
                FilmSound.start();
            }
        }
    });
    Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.greentea);
    button4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (FilmSound.isPlaying()) {
                FilmSound.stop();
                FilmSound.reset();
                FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.raw.greentea);
                FilmSound.start();
            } else {
                FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.raw.greentea);
                FilmSound.start();
            }
        }
    });
    Button button11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.havefun);
    button11.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (FilmSound.isPlaying()) {
                FilmSound.stop();
                FilmSound.reset();
                FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.raw.havefun);
                FilmSound.start();
            } else {
                FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.raw.havefun);
                FilmSound.start();
            }
        }
    });
    Button button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
            R.raw.kisswashot);
    button6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (FilmSound.isPlaying()) {
                FilmSound.stop();
                FilmSound.reset();
                FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.raw.kisswashot);
                FilmSound.start();
            } else {
                FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.raw.kisswashot);
                FilmSound.start();
            }
        }
    });
    Button button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.ohshit);
    button7.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (FilmSound.isPlaying()) {
                FilmSound.stop();
                FilmSound.reset();
                FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.raw.ohshit);
                FilmSound.start();
            } else {
                FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.raw.ohshit);
                FilmSound.start();
            }
        }
    });
    Button button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
            R.raw.throwingstar);
    button8.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (FilmSound.isPlaying()) {
                FilmSound.stop();
                FilmSound.reset();
                FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.raw.throwingstar);
                FilmSound.start();
            } else {
                FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.raw.throwingstar);
                FilmSound.start();
            }
        }
    });
    Button button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
            R.raw.twolegittwoquit);
    button9.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (FilmSound.isPlaying()) {
                FilmSound.stop();
                FilmSound.reset();
                FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.raw.twolegittwoquit);
                FilmSound.start();
            } else {
                FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.raw.twolegittwoquit);
                FilmSound.start();
            }
        }
    });
    Button button10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.whiskey);
    button10.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (FilmSound.isPlaying()) {
                FilmSound.stop();
                FilmSound.reset();
                FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.raw.whiskey);
                FilmSound.start();
            } else {
                FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.raw.whiskey);
                FilmSound.start();
            }
        }
    });
    Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.demons);
    button5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (FilmSound.isPlaying()) {
                FilmSound.stop();
                FilmSound.reset();
                FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.raw.demons);
                FilmSound.start();
            } else {
                FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.raw.demons);
                FilmSound.start();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here is the code with prepare:

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                R.raw.animalkingdom);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    FilmSound.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (FilmSound.isPlaying()) {
                    FilmSound.stop();
                    FilmSound.reset();

                    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                            R.raw.animalkingdom);
                    FilmSound.start();
                } else {
                    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                            R.raw.animalkingdom);
                    FilmSound.start();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: You can't just stop and start and create a MediaPlayer. You have to wait for it to be prepared, then start. See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html scroll down to the example

Comment: It's Android Market God trying to speak to you in his loud voice : "Yet again another soundboard you shall not post !!" :D Just kidding :)

Comment: @Yahel I know right, but it's supposed to be a simple starter app for me to learn. "Android Market God" Hilarious.

Answer (score 10):

I just had a similar issue. I solved it by simply adding the following to your manifest file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Prior to ICS no Internet Permission was required.

Answer (score 0):

After you create the `MediaPlayer`, try preparing it:

```
FilmSound.prepare();
```

Comment: @ Matthew I tried to prepare the media player with that code and i'm still getting unable to create media player.

Comment: Are you able to play your file with known working code, such as API Demos? You may try it there first as a sanity check.

Comment: what's worse is it works fine on android 2.2. I can't get it to work on any os version below that.

Answer (score 0):

Check this question out: [Android -- Can't play any videos (mp4/mov/3gp/etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544365/android-cant-play-any-videos-mp4-mov-3gp-etc)

Have you tried playing a file in a different format? Maybe your sound requires some codec that Android doesn't have, so the prepare() fails.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `create()` method outside of the `onClickListener`. Right now when you start the app it will create 10 instances of FilmSound since the code is outside of onClickListener, then when you click a button it will create the 11th instance of FilmSound.  Likely this is running out of memory below Android 2.2.  You don't need to prepare after using the `create()` method, it will prepare after create the first time.

Also, I'm pretty sure `isPlaying()` can throw exceptions.

```
if (FilmSound != null) {
try {
        if (FilmSound.isPlaying()) { 
             FilmSound.release(); 
             FilmSound = null;
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {FilmSound= new MediaPlayer(); }};

if (FilmSound == null) {
    FilmSound= new MediaPlayer(); 
}
    FilmSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, clip);
    FilmSound.start();
    FilmSound.setOnCompletionListener(this);
```