# How to make mp4 video files open in native video players on iPhone and Android?

Tags: iphone, android, browser, video, mobile

I am trying to make video files open in native Android and iPhone video players instead of playing on the web page. Right now I do it with a regular link `Standard` which does not work on Android and not always working on iPhone. What can I do to make it work?

Comment: Check this post hope it works for android<br><br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544365/android-cant-play-any-videos-mp4-mov-3gp-etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing to a .m4v extension may fix your problem with opening in the iPhone video player.

Comment: The problem is on Android phones, not on iPhone... ((

Comment: This should fix it not always working on iPhones, but I don't have any experience with Android video, so I can't help you there.