# Playing video in android

Tags: android, video

I have 4 .mp4 videos that I need to play in an android app. I managed to play 1 video, but the other 3 won't play. I think video size is the issue. The video that I managed to play has a size of 1.4mb and the other 3 have a size of 6mb, 2.2mb, 3.8mb.

Here's my code for playing them.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_videoviewer);

         Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {   
                String value = extras.getString("VidName");

                if(value.equals("MinorBurnVid"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                    videoView1 = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.Video1);

                    videoView1.setVideoPath("android.resource://dr.droid/" + R.raw.burn);
                    videoView1.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
                    videoView1.requestFocus();
                    videoView1.start();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else if(value.equals("ChokingAdultVid"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        videoView1 = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.Video1);

                        videoView1.setVideoPath("android.resource://dr.droid/" + R.raw.chokingadult);
                        videoView1.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
                        videoView1.requestFocus();
                        videoView1.start();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                }
                else if(value.equals("CPRAdultVid"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        videoView1 = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.Video1);

                        videoView1.setVideoPath("android.resource://dr.droid/" + R.raw.cpr);
                        videoView1.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
                        videoView1.requestFocus();
                        videoView1.start();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                }
                else if(value.equals("Fracture"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        videoView1 = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.Video1);

                        videoView1.setVideoPath("android.resource://dr.droid/" + R.raw.fracture);
                        videoView1.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
                        videoView1.requestFocus();
                        videoView1.start();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                }
            }

    }
```

The burn video is the one that I managed to play but the other 3, no luck! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an exception or is it just ignoring the code snippet? If there are no exceptions make sure the string stored in "value" is correct, it could be a minor problem like being case-sensitive. Hopefully.

Comment: No errors/exceptions. Just an alert upon clicking the button saying can't play this video. I doubt that it the problem is in the string value since it can recognize that a particular video is not able to play.

Comment: Then it would probably be the video size. But a 6mb file shouldn't be too large. I will do some research and try to get back to you on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
String uri = "android.resource://dr.droid/" + R.raw.fracture;
videoView1.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri));
```

Comment: If this is the solution. Why do you think 1 video is playing while the other 3 won't?

Comment: sorry, my mistake. i have check your code and it is right. And the size of video is not the problem.

Comment: what do you think is the problem? i already did some compression to lessen the video size and still the other videos won't play. only the burn one.

Comment: may be the format of the videos. see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012494/sorry-this-video-cannot-be-played-streaming-mp4-to-android) for detail