# Android YouTube API for playing video other than YouTube video

Tags: android, youtube-api, video-streaming

I want to play videos hosted in Google drive in android application.
I can play video in web browser via private url of video.

I want to know that can I use android youtube api for playing this video ?

If yes, possibly give any example..

Or suggest any other ways

Thanks

Comment: Sorry you cannot use youtube api to play other than youtube video, youtube api is dedicated to youtube videos only and you can play videos by passing youtube video id.

Answer (score 0):

`MediaPlayer` and `VideoView` (wrapper of `MediaPlayer`) should work on external video URL.

Comment: Hello Sir, Thanks for reply. I have tried it before this but some problems are there because I want to play video from google drive. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24753075/how-to-show-video-in-android-from-google-drive-url