# Android Stream video from Google drive

Tags: android, webview, google-drive-api

i am building an Android app that need to Stream video from Google drive the video link is like that : https:// docs.google.com/file/d/--ID--

i can't get the rtsp so it can't run the video in a videoview and it doesn't end with mp4 or 3gp... so i can't run it like that :

> Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
> intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("https:// docs.google.com/file/d/--ID--"),
> "video/mp4"); view.getContext().startActivity(intent);

i was able to run the video in webView using this code :

> webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
> webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
> webview.loadUrl("https:// docs.google.com/file/d/--ID--");
>
> webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

but the video can't be played full screen and it can't be paused and it lag ...

so what should i do ? is there anyway to stream the video from Google drive

Comment: Is just downloading the file an option? Download it and send an intent to start it with a video player app. If your video format is not supported by [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html), then that's not an option. You can use players like [ExoPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html), but you'll have to significantly change your implementation as you can't just pass a Drive url to it.

Comment: i want to stream the video without downloading the file when i tried to stream the video in computer browser i was able to get a direct link that i could send to an intent to start it with a video player app
<div class="html5-video-container">
 <video class="video-stream html5-main-video" src="https://r17---sn-hpa7ln7s.c.docs.google.com/videoplayba....">
 </video>
</div>
but the problem this link appear in page html source only when i click play button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I am trying this also and I can find a solution by myself

1: make sure video url is https://drive.google.com/file/d/VIDEO-ID/preview"

2: I download web content from the above url and get direct video url:

```
public String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(myurl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            is = conn.getInputStream();
            String contentAsString = readIt(is);
            return contentAsString;
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

//Get direct video url from stream output

```
public String readIt(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains("fmt_stream_map")) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
                break;
            }
        }
        reader.close();
        String result = decode(sb.toString());
        String[] url = result.split("\\|");
        return url[1]; 
    }
```

//We need a function to decode url to normal use

```
public String decode(String in) {
        String working = in;
        int index;
        index = working.indexOf("\\u");
        while (index > -1) {
            int length = working.length();
            if (index > (length - 6)) break;
            int numStart = index + 2;
            int numFinish = numStart + 4;
            String substring = working.substring(numStart, numFinish);
            int number = Integer.parseInt(substring, 16);
            String stringStart = working.substring(0, index);
            String stringEnd = working.substring(numFinish);
            working = stringStart + ((char) number) + stringEnd;
            index = working.indexOf("\\u");
        }
        return working;
    }
```

After i use thes three function now I can get a direct video url that return by `readtIt(InputStream stream)` as a string and I can use it for parsing to VideoView.

Comment: would this work in case of file at server? Like, if my video is stored at server, and I send the file in string format as above, and parse it in my VideoView, would it work?

Comment: the code above work only for video store in google drive

Comment: `Value of line variables` fetched from `BufferedReader` `(reader.readLine())`doen't contain `fmt_stream_map.`

So my `StringBuilder` is `empty` after `executing this code`

Comment: This is just kind of hack. Google has change their markup , so it stop working