# How to stream a video file to VideoView using Google Drive Android Api?

Tags: google-drive-android-api

I managed to upload video file to Google Drive using google-drive-android-api, now I can't find a way to watch that video directly from Google Drive(not downloading the file) just stream it. 
How can I accomplish it?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596614/android-stream-video-from-google-drive

Comment: Unfortunately, Android Drive API does not support streaming. You can use the REST API to do that.

Comment: Can you give me a hint what is the best way of doing this with REST API?