# iOS Stream video from Google drive Swift

Tags: android, ios, swift, video-streaming

I'm building an iOS app that Stream's video from Google drive the videos link looks like this

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2Kri7-TaAFJSlJ4UTJuSElGamM/preview

The only way to get the Stream Link from the URL above is by Decoding the webView HTML

#### Code:

```
let myURLString = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2Kri7-TaAFJSlJ4UTJuSElGamM/preview"

    if let myURL = NSURL(string: myURLString) {

        do {
            let myHTMLString = try String(contentsOfURL: myURL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("HTML : \(myHTMLString)")

        } catch {
            print("Error : \(error)")
        }
    } else {
        print("Error: \(myURLString) doesn't  URL")
    }
```

after doing that i get the HTML for the webView

**The problem is :**

What I'm looking for in the HTML is this "**fmt_stream_map**" this contain is all the Streaming Links that I need too Stream the video but I don't know how to access it and get the Steam Links from it.

**PS:** I'm Working with an Android Developer and he told me he used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33625394/5605581) method to solve the issue but he couldn't explain it to me and I don't know java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem using the method :

```
        let myURLString = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1XhqDeOfqG7UWZSaG1ZbFFhSzQ/preview"

    if let myURL = NSURL(string: myURLString) {

        do {
            let myHTMLString = try String(contentsOfURL: myURL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            let t = myHTMLString

            if let rangeOfZero = t.rangeOfString("plid", options: NSStringCompareOptions.BackwardsSearch) {

                let suffix = String(t.characters.suffixFrom(rangeOfZero.endIndex))

                //    print(suffix)

                let input = "\(suffix)"
                let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingType.Link.rawValue)
                let matches = detector.matchesInString(input, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: input.utf8.count))

                //  print(matches)
                for match in matches {

                    let url = (input as NSString).substringWithRange(match.range)

                    linksA.append(url)

                }

                theLink()

            } else {
                print("noooo")
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error : \(error)")
        }
    } else {
        print("Error: \(myURLString) doesn't  URL")
    }
```

afther that you need to decode the streaming link using this method :

```
    func theLink() {


    /// /[u]00../g


    let firstElement = linksA.first

    let t = firstElement!.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(",35", withString: "")

    let deUrl = t.characters.split{$0 == "|"}.map(String.init)

    let link = deUrl[0]

    // the link needs to be decoded

    let i = link.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)


    let p = i!.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("%5Cu", withString: "")


    // you can see how the link should look like here :
    // http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/?results=d82d4e564eccc1a6b96ee7c5c1e1c3b2

    // %252C : ,
    // 003d : =
    // 0026 : &

     let re = p.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("003d", withString: "=")
     let y = re.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("0026", withString: "&")
        let c = y.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("%252C", withString: ",")

    print(c) }
```

you can see all the code [**Here**](https://github.com/DevZaid/GDSLink)