# play video in videoview where source is Google Drive shared link (https)

Tags: android, google-drive-api, android-videoview

What is the right way to play video which reside on Google Drive using VideoView control ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the url format of the video from Drive and display it in [Android WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://drive.google.com/file/d/VIDEO_ID/view");
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
 startActivity(intent);
```

You may also check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596614/android-stream-video-from-google-drive/33625394#33625394) for other workaround.