# How to play videos from a Google Drive link in android?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am enabled to view video from google drive link. I have tried to view video using webview as well as videoview.
Tried below solutions also:

- [Android Stream video from Google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596614/android-stream-video-from-google-drive/33625394#33625394)
- [How to show video in android from google drive url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24753075/how-to-show-video-in-android-from-google-drive-url)

Logs :

2021-12-15 22:24:55.167 1003-1057/? E/SurfaceFlinger: notifyInputMotion motionType=2
2021-12-15 22:24:55.171 1600-1847/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.display.disable_rounded_corner"
2021-12-15 22:24:55.184 2927-2952/? E/IHansComunication: HANS printMessageBody: RCVed message body: type = 0, port = 86870, caller_pid = 1600, target_uid = 10151, pkg_cmd = -1
2021-12-15 22:24:55.189 2927-2952/? E/IHansComunication: HANS printMessageBody: RCVed message body: type = 0, port = 86870, caller_pid = 1600, target_uid = 10016, pkg_cmd = -1
2021-12-15 22:24:55.192 2927-2952/? E/IHansComunication: HANS printMessageBody: RCVed message body: type = 0, port = 86870, caller_pid = 1600, target_uid = 10259, pkg_cmd = -1
2021-12-15 22:24:55.194 2927-2952/? E/IHansComunication: HANS printMessageBody: RCVed message body: type = 0, port = 86870, caller_pid = 1600, target_uid = 10069, pkg_cmd = -1
2021-12-15 22:24:55.555 2927-2952/? E/IHansComunication: HANS printMessageBody: RCVed message body: type = 0, port = 86870, caller_pid = 1600, target_uid = 10016, pkg_cmd = -1
2021-12-15 22:24:55.561 2927-2952/? E/IHansComunication: HANS printMessageBody: RCVed message body: type = 0, port = 86870, caller_pid = 1600, target_uid = 10069, pkg_cmd = -1
2021-12-15 22:24:55.573 4090-8504/? E/CarrierServices: [225] bvs.k: (RCS): [VPN]: NetworkType 17 not found.
2021-12-15 22:24:58.388 3922-3962/? E/horae: 0: -4.12, +(2000), 1
2021-12-15 22:24:58.729 1600-1847/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.display.disable_rounded_corner"
2021-12-15 22:24:58.750 2927-2952/? E/IHansComunication: HANS printMessageBody: RCVed message body: type = 0, port = 86870, caller_pid = 1600, target_uid = 10151, pkg_cmd = -1
2021-12-15 22:24:58.756 2927-2952/? E/IHansComunication: HANS printMessageBody: RCVed message body: type = 0, port = 86870, caller_pid = 1600, target_uid = 10016, pkg_cmd = -1
2021-12-15 22:24:58.757 2927-2952/? E/IHansComunication: HANS printMessageBody: RCVed message body: type = 0, port = 86870, caller_pid = 1600, target_uid = 10259, pkg_cmd = -1
2021-12-15 22:24:58.758 2927-2952/? E/IHansComunication: HANS printMessageBody: RCVed message body: type = 0, port = 86870, caller_pid = 1600, target_uid = 10069, pkg_cmd = -1
2021-12-15 22:25:04.637 2927-2952/? E/IHansComunication: HANS printMessageBody: RCVed message body: type = 0, port = 86870, caller_pid = 1600, target_uid = 10016, pkg_cmd = -1
2021-12-15 22:25:04.643 2927-2952/? E/IHansComunication: HANS printMessageBody: RCVed message body: type = 0, port = 86870, caller_pid = 1600, target_uid = 10069, pkg_cmd = -1
2021-12-15 22:25:04.656 4090-8504/? E/CarrierServices: [225] bvs.k: (RCS): [VPN]: NetworkType 17 not found.
2021-12-15 22:25:05.002 2458-2458/? E/ndroid.systemu: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2021-12-15 22:25:05.003 2458-2458/? E/ndroid.systemu: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2021-12-15 22:25:05.840 17804-17815/? E/EMBMSSL_SERVER: EmbmsServerImpl::broadcastCoverageNotification state : 1
2021-12-15 22:25:05.840 17804-17815/? E/EMBMSSL_SERVER: EmbmsServerImpl::radioStateNotification  mnn: 405 , mnc: 864 , cellId: 6462490
2021-12-15 22:25:05.975 2458-2458/? E/OpReflectionUtils: getValue NoSuchField class com.android.keyguard.CarrierTextController field mIsEmergencyCallCapable
2021-12-15 22:25:05.979 2458-2458/? E/OpReflectionUtils: getValue NoSuchField class com.android.keyguard.CarrierTextController field mIsEmergencyCallCapable
2021-12-15 22:25:05.982 2458-2458/? E/OpReflectionUtils: getValue NoSuchField class com.android.keyguard.CarrierTextController field mIsEmergencyCallCapable
2021-12-15 22:25:09.601 17804-17815/? E/EMBMSSL_SERVER: EmbmsServerImpl::broadcastCoverageNotification state : 1
2021-12-15 22:25:09.601 17804-17815/? E/EMBMSSL_SERVER: EmbmsServerImpl::radioStateNotification  mnn: 405 , mnc: 864 , cellId: 4160275
2021-12-15 22:25:09.734 2458-2458/? E/OpReflectionUtils: getValue NoSuchField class com.android.keyguard.CarrierTextController field mIsEmergencyCallCapable
2021-12-15 22:25:09.738 2458-2458/? E/OpReflectionUtils: getValue NoSuchField class com.android.keyguard.CarrierTextController field mIsEmergencyCallCapable
2021-12-15 22:25:09.741 2458-2458/? E/OpReflectionUtils: getValue NoSuchField class com.android.keyguard.CarrierTextController field mIsEmergencyCallCapable

Comment: What error you are getting ? can you please copy paste the logs in your question?

Comment: @SoftwareGuy Updated Question with log