# raw folder video in listview are gridview

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I want to display raw/ assets folder videos files in Gridview or in Listview.

-please are there any samples or any links.

Thanks,
chandu

Answer (score 0):

Go for the links. This contain a simple example.
http://androidsamples.blogspot.in/2009/06/displaying-list-of-video-files-stored.html

And also you can go for the [Android -- Can't play any videos (mp4/mov/3gp/etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544365/android-cant-play-any-videos-mp4-mov-3gp-etc). second answer contains one demo. You can go for that. Njoy