# Android: how to run video from resource folder

Tags: android

I have already seen the other questions similar to mine, but the problem persists.
Thanks in advance.

Here's the code

```
package com.akk.mysecondvideo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MySecondVideo extends Activity {

Context context;
MediaPlayer mp;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
    //MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    // mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    //videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.akk.mysecondvideo/"
            + R.raw.bommarillu);

    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);

    //mp = new MediaPlayer();
    //mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.bommarillu);


    videoView.start(); 
}
}
```

It shows a force close when i try to run it, and the logcat shows error `NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION` in line 28 which is `videoView.setVideoURI(uri);`

VideoView is part of main.xml.
The main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<VideoView 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:id="@+id/VideoView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your main.xml file. Is videoview a part of main.xml?

Comment: can you share your Layout as well please

Comment: @ValayPatel main.xml is added

Comment: @Akhil yes, videoview is part of main

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play videos in android from assets folder or raw folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028717/how-to-play-videos-in-android-from-assets-folder-or-raw-folder)

Answer (score 1):

Did you check to see if `uri` is `null`?

Try adding this line before `videoView.setVidoeURI(uri)` :

```
if (null == uri)
   Toast.makeText(this, "URI IS NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

If the toast notification shows up then the URI didn't parse correctly

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but now its showing **can't play this video**

Comment: does video is in supported format? http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#formats-table go to video section of this table

Comment: seems this is the case, as my video is in .mp4 format, which doesn't seem to be supported, thanks!

Comment: @Selvin sorry about previous comment, but it says that it supports .mp4 as well as .3gp format, while i am not able to run either

Comment: It says, can't play video, video not supported!

Comment: @Ashwyn see these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263736/playing-a-video-in-videoview-in-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806261/strange-behavior-of-android-videoview-cant-play-video  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544365/android-cant-play-any-videos-mp4-mov-3gp-etc

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any problem as such. But couple of suggestions I would like to tell you

- Name the widget in XML different than the widget name e.g myVideoView instead of VideoView
- videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
- videoView.requestFocus();

Check if this works. I have the same code as you I will create a project and will give you my inputs.

Till that time try this

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.akk.mysecondvideo/raw/bommarillu");
```